# "Expected string or buffer" error using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying a code that will pull numbers from a URL using Beautiful Soup, then sum these numbers, but I keep getting an error that looks like this:

> Expected string or buffer

I think it's related to the regular expressions, but I can't pinpoint the problem.

```
import re
import urllib

from BeautifulSoup import *
htm1 = urllib.urlopen('https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/comments_42.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htm1)
tags = soup('span')

for tag in tags:
    y = re.findall ('([0-9]+)',tag.txt)

print sum(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `bs4` instead of `BeautifulSoup` (which is the old version). You also need to change this line:

```
y = re.findall ('([0-9]+)',tag)
```

to something like this:

```
y = re.findall ('([0-9]+)',tag.text)
```

See if this gets you further:

```
sum = 0  #initialize the sum
for tag in tags:
    y = re.findall ('([0-9]+)',tag.text)  #get the text from the tag                                                                                                                                    
    print(y[0])  #y is a list, print the first element of the list                                                                                                                                      
    sum += int(y[0])  #convert it to an integer and add it to the sum                                                                                                                                   

print('the sum is: {}'.format(sum))
```

Comment: You're right when I changed the line as per your suggestion I got past the error, but the code still doesn't work as intended. I tried installing bs4 last week, and couldn't get it to install right, so I decided to stick with bs3.

Comment: Please update  your code above to your current version - my test looked like you were close.

Comment: What do you mean by current version? I'm using Python 2.7 and bs3

Comment: I mean you modified your code to use `tag.text` to get past the error - can you edit the code snippet in your question above to show what you have currently?

Comment: I updated the code. I'm not really used to Stackoverflow.com. I'm a newbie.

Comment: I think if you integrate my answer you'll be almost there. I left in some debugging output.

Comment: @Julia_arch glad to hear that!